# Show view in front of soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, popupwindow, android-dialogfragment

I have a screen like below.

[image: Screenshot]

Screen 1 is the initial screen. It contains a Layout at top, EditText and + button below it.

When I click on the EditText then soft keyboard comes up (Screen 2).

When I click on + button then a View comes on top of soft keyboard. This View contains a Viewpager with 4 tabs and 4 Fragments.
This custom View must be in front of keyboard (Keyboard should be still there but behind this view). When I hide this View then Keyboard should be there behind this View.

How can I show a View in front of soft keyboard? I tried doing this using DialogFragment and PopupWindow.

Problem with DialogFragment is that it can't be shown in front of keyboard.

Problem with PopupWindow is that if I show ViewPager in PopupWindow then it gives "IlligalArgumentException No view found for id 0X001272" inside first Fragment of ViewPager.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me out. What is the best way to show something in front of keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want another layer in front of the soft keyboard such as **WhatsApp** emoticons and smileys which appear as a popup over the soft keyboard, you can use [**Emojicon**](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) library. It should, at least, give you an idea of how to implement it.

Comment: The library you suggested is good, however, my case is different. In my case I want the EmojiView to have a ViewPager with Fragments. The Emojicon library have ViewPager with just GridViews. When I use Fragments I get that exception I mentioned in my question "IlligalArgumentException No view found for id 0X001272".